# Database design for an abstract entity

Tags: php, database-design, doctrine-orm, orm, nosql

I have an abstract entity called `Campaign` and a number of final entities like `FooCampaign`, `BarCampaign` and so on. This set is open-ended. All of the final entities have the common fields described in the abstract entity. The common fields can change over time, not frequently though - I might want to add more shared fields or remove some of them. The same is relevant for the fields of the final entities. I was wondering of a database design for this and these are the options I'm considering:

1. Relational database, one table for the common fields and a table for every final entity, one to one relation between them.
2. Relational database, only one table, any unique fields for the final entities are kept in a JSON column.
3. NoSQL database.

My application is written in PHP (Symfony 4), so I'm keen to use Doctrine. I tend to use the option #2 subconsciously, but really unaware of pros and cons of any of these of options. I need to be able to query campaigns based on the unique fields, the speed is also matters.

What of the options would fit my case better and are there any other alternatives?

**UPDATE**

[Doctrine inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), mentioned in the first comment, seems to fit my case perfectly. But why even bother with this when there are nosql database like Mongo for schemaless data (my data is not exactly schemaless though)? So the question is RDBMS with inheritance mapping VS NoSQL.

Comment: Your use case seems to be a perfect fit for [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). You still can chose to go with one table or multiple table. I have solved something similar (asset management, where an asset could be a PDF or a JPEG or a docx; sharing certain data but each also had unique data)  through single table mapping in the past and it worked well. Yet it may depend on your use case.

Comment: @k0pernikus Right seems it fits perfectly. I'm only in doubts about RDBMS vs NoSQL now.

Comment: In the end, you shouldn't spend too much time on deciding which road to follow. Go with whatever solution you feel is more comfortable to you. I argue that all the downsides of either approach will most likely not affect you. Both mysql and nosql will be good enough. I personally would be biased towards the Single Table Inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

When campaign comes into the picture, I assume or predict there will be lot of requirements to run different queries returning analytics of the data you have. For this you need more flexibility and ability to access each small record for a campaign where you can run your analytics queries. Having json data will limit you a lot if you are keeping different fields serialized in a single json column.

My suggestion if you would like to go with MySQL:

So you have campaign table with all your command fields as you mentioned. For dynamic fields you can have second table as below :

```
id  campaign_id field_name  field_value
1   1   area    somearea
2   1   budget  100
3   2   area    anotherarea
4   2   owner   someowner
5   2   is_prime    TRUE
```

So campaign_id will be a foreign key from campaigns table, field_name and field_value are you dynamic fields which are changed. This will give you flexibility to add any number of dynamica fields for your campaign entity, eliminating the worry of managing the data.

I would personally love going with NoSQL like Mongo, just because I do not need to worry about strong relationships. I can have as much flexibility to have campaign data as possible. And not to mention, Mongo has great aggregation functions(MySQL has too :)) so there is nothing limiting. It would be personal preference at the end.

Comment: Yep I would agree about NoSQL. If the nature of my data model is like this, why I should bother with relational databases. Just don't have much practical experience with it and it seems a bit overcomplicating the things. On the other end I don't like the idea of messing with the inheritance mapping in a relational DB.

Comment: I did not consider inheritance mapping initially. But I guess you can do with RDBMS, just check if the data in your system other than campaigns  is relational or its entirely campaign driven(flexible). :)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, you were talking about something EAV-like. It would be very slow to query, lots of joins. It's a microservice, so it's campaign driven.

Comment: Its not exactly EAV but as its giving you flexibility will be at a cost of having little large queries. But if queried in right way with proper indexes, this shouldn't be a problem at all even if extremely large data. But the more I think about it, NoSQL give me strong feelings to choose :)